# Choropleth map in R

Tags: r, choropleth

I am trying to customize the Choropleth map. Below you can see my code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)

datar <- data.frame(GEO = c("AR","AZ","TR","GA","IR"), 
                    Value = c(0.2560,0.023,0.0120,0.158,0.0025),
                    search_countries = factor(c("Armenia","Azerbaijan","Turkey","Georgia","Iran")),
                    countries = c("Armenia","Azerbaijan","Turkey","Georgia","Iran")
)

mapa <- map_data('world', region = datar$search_countries)

ggplot() + 
  geom_map(data = mapa, map = mapa, aes(x = long, y = lat,map_id = region)) +
  geom_map(data = datar, map = mapa, aes(fill = Value, map_id = countries), color ='white', size = .25) +
  coord_map()
```

This code shows the values with colors, but additionally, I want to see values ( 0.2560,0.023,0.0120,0.158,0.0025 in each of these countries inside the map. So can anybody help me how to solve this problem and put values inside the map?